# Saving a txt file containing comma separated values as .csv file in numbers on Mac

Tags: csv

I have a raw data in following format in Atom;

```
DateofDeath,Name,Age,PlaceofDeath,Decision,yearOfDeath,gender,fractionalDeathYear,ageBracket,gender2
17-Mar-75,Eva Lyons,70,Own home,Unlawful killing,1975,0,1974.71,70-74,Women
07-Aug-78,Sarah Hannah Marsland,86,Own home,Unlawful killing,1978,0,1978.1,85-89,Women
30-Aug-78,Mary Ellen Jordan,73,Own home,Unlawful killing,1978,0,1978.16,70-74,Women
07-Dec-78,Harold Bramwell,73,Own home,Unlawful killing,1978,1,1978.44,70-74,Men
```

As you can see it is comma separated fields. but I want to save it a .csv in Numbers on Mac. If I just copy and paste I am getting all contents in one column. Can I please get some help here?

[image]

[enter link description here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dspiegel29/ArtofStatistics/master/00-2-shipman-times/00-2-shipman-times-x.csv)

Comment: Hmm, I can copy-paste your sample data into the top-left cell in Numbers and it correctly interprets the data as CSV and spilts out the columns and rows. Have you tried just _opening the CSV_ in Number (no copy-paste)?

Comment: @ZachYoung I tried to copy paste in th left cell in numbers. plz see screenshot above. is that what I am supposed to see? I was hoping into get split into columns properly.
For sake of example, I have attached a link above . I am trying to copy that type of data into numbers. Can you help here, if possible?

Comment: No, I'm not sure why that's happening for you and not for me. Have you updated Numbers (latest version)? **_But_**, what happens when you **_just open_** the file with Numbers (don't try to copy-paste)?